# Sonarqube missing blame files

Tags: maven, junit, sonarqube, pom.xml

I'm writing a program in java building it with Maven in an Intelij environment. I'm using pom.xln files. For some reason maven doesn't see my UnitTest files. I get a warnining : Missing blame information for the following files: TestUnit etc. As a result my Sonar report says that my test cover 0%.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmNLF.png)[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zp9M.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oEWM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qs9xD.png)

I already tried changing the files multiple times but that only made it worst, and made more fires have missing blame information.